# jquery how is $(this) really stored?

Tags: jquery

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/dg2Hp/) basic example:

```
<div id="cont">
   <input type=button value='button'>  
</div>
<input type=button value='button'>
```

And the script:

```
$('input').click(function(){
    console.log($(this));
    console.log($('#cont').has($(this)));
    console.log($('#cont').has($(this)).length);
    console.log("---");
    });​
```

In both button-click the value of `$(this)` according to console.log are same:

```
[<input type=​"button" value=​"button">​]
```

Why are they give still different results?

In other words some information does not represented when I console log $(this). This information may points to the element unique id. But what is it, where is it stored? Why does it not showed in the log?

Comment: It should, you bind the click with button, and click on a button with same name and type should make same output

Comment: add some identifier to those buttons like id, and check then

Comment: they are deliberately the same

Comment: So is `console.log({})` and `console.log({})` yet they both refer to different objects (ie `{} !== {}`)

Comment: I'm looking for the difference and where is it stored, or how is it really work.

Answer (score 0):

It only looks like it's the same since the buttons have the same markup.

[Edited example](http://jsfiddle.net/tricki/dg2Hp/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you're asking. Using `this` in jQuery functions is relative to the element the event is happening on. In your case the particular input that a click event is happening on. Though both of your inputs have the same HTML they are different elements. So if you click on the one outside of the `#cont` div the `console.log($('#cont').has($(this)));` should not return anything.

Answer (score 0):

According to the API spec

"Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .has() method constructs a new jQuery object from a subset of the matching elements. The supplied selector is tested against the descendants of the matching elements; the element will be included in the result if any of its descendant elements matches the selector."

http://api.jquery.com/has/

the return results of '$('#cont').has($(this))' is not a boolean but the matching object.

In you're case the div with id 'cont' contains the first button but not the second.

So pressing the first button returns the containg div in the has function & pressing the second object returns no div because the div doesn't contain the button